# Display all name that search when we type the first letter for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar

I want to search all names that start with a particular letter, that means when I type one character in search bar it will show all names that start with that character but unfortunately it also shows the names that contain this character.I want to show only those names that start with a particular character that I type in search bar . Please show me the solution.

```
 - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBars textDidChange:(NSString *)search
 {

 if(search.length == 0)
 {
    isFiltered = FALSE;
 } 
 else{

    isFiltered=true;
    itemData =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Item *itemsearch in listOfItemForStock) {

        NSString *stringId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",itemsearch.iditem];
        NSString *stringName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",itemsearch.name];
        NSRange idRange = [stringId rangeOfString:search options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)];
        NSRange nameRange = [stringName rangeOfString:search options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)];

        if(idRange.location!=NSNotFound || nameRange.location != NSNotFound){

            [self.itemData addObject:itemsearch];
        }
    }
}    

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Comment: You are filtering the names at searchbar delegate, aren't you ?

Comment: Yes I want to filter the name at searchbar delegate

Comment: Do you need it only when one character is entered ? I see there's also an id search, not just name.

Comment: my example, now it works

Comment: If you don't need the id search and you want to search only the by the name only from beginning, your sample was almost correct. you'll need to delete `idRange.location != NSNotFound` condition and use the search condition you used like if (yourComparisonCode) { [self.itemData addObject:itemsearch]; }

Comment: Thanks A-Live, I have done it with id and name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name check to a prefix check.  Replace the nameRange variable with a BOOL that only indicates whether the stringName begins with the search string...

```
/// ...
BOOL nameMatches = [[stringName lowercaseString] hasPrefix:[search lowercaseString]];

if(idRange.location!=NSNotFound || nameMatches){
    //..
```

Answer (score 0):

if(idRange.location!=NSNotFound || nameRange.location != NSNotFound){

```
            NSComparisonResult result = [itemsearch.name compare:search options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [search length])];
            NSComparisonResult resultId = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",itemsearch.iditem ] compare:search options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [search length])];

            if (result == NSOrderedSame || resultId == NSOrderedSame){
                [self.itemData addObject:itemsearch];
            }
        }
```